# how to get parameters name of stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I want to create generic function that will need only parameter as Stored procedure name and will return the collection of the parameter list of that stored procedure. how to achieve this in c#.
OR
another way :-

can we write the stored procedure that will have the parameter as names of another SP let say as varchar type, and will return the list of parameters of passed SP , in sql server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `DeriveParameters` method that belongs to the `SqlCommandBuilder` class. [Here is an example.](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/11/01/SqlCommandBuilderDeriveParameters.aspx)